# R dataset with $ NULL:'data.frame'?

Tags: r, dataset

it may be a dummy questions but I'm really stuck here.

I have the following dataset in R:

```
> str(he)
List of 1
 $ NULL:'data.frame':   29 obs. of  10 variables:
  ..$ Date    : Factor w/ 4 levels "","October 15, 2014 4:13 PM",..: 3 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 ...
  ..$ Receipt : Factor w/ 14 levels "","-1 Discount",..: 14 3 7 5 2 13 4 8 6 12 ...
  ..$ Register: Factor w/ 11 levels "-300.00","-400.00",..: 11 7 4 4 1 11 5 4 4 11 ...
  ..$ User    : Factor w/ 4 levels "","Cash","Credit Card",..: 4 1 1 1 1 4 3 1 1 4 ...
  ..$ Customer: Factor w/ 4 levels "","1,000.00",..: 1 NA NA NA NA 1 2 NA NA 1 ...
  ..$ Notes   : Factor w/ 1 level "": 1 NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA NA 1 ...
  ..$ Products: Factor w/ 1 level "Total sale": 1 NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA NA 1 ...
  ..$ Total   : Factor w/ 3 levels "0.00","1,000.00",..: 1 NA NA NA NA 2 NA NA NA 3 ...
  ..$ Payments: Factor w/ 1 level "Total paid": 1 NA NA NA NA 1 NA NA NA 1 ...
  ..$ Paid    : Factor w/ 3 levels "0.00","1,000.00",..: 1 NA NA NA NA 2 NA NA NA 3 ...
```

However, I don't seem to be able to access the data. For instance:

```
> he$Date
NULL
```

There is something about this $ NULL:'data.frame'. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: Here `he` is not a `data.frame`, but a list of one entry (index NULL) that contains a `data.frame`. Do `he <- he[[1]]` to get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `str(he)` output says it all. List of 1... means that your data.frame is residing within your list.
The best thing would be to either re-assign 'he' to actually be a data.frame, or create a new data.frame to then reference the elements within it. E.g

```
df_he <- he[[1]]
df_he$date
```